# Image manipulation using PHP: force 1:1 aspect ratio (sqaure images)

Tags: php, javascript

I am looking to add a background to images that users upload that are not square. So if they upload a tall and skinny photo I want to add a white background to the sides of the image to make the resulting image have an aspect ratio of 1:1. Is this possible using PHP or javascript?

Comment: I maintain that my original answer was an answer because the question was "Is this possible using php or javascript," but have you looked into the extensions found in: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: Did you search SO? There are a lot of Q&A's on this subject. For example: [PHP Image Resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553247/php-image-resizing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GD library is the most commonly used image manipulation package. It's a set of functions often installed with PHP which handle image manipulation.

What you'll want to do is either scale and crop your image to a specific aspect ratio so that you place your image on a square canvas and cut off whatever does fit or

You'll want to simply resize your image to a fixed aspect ratio and place it on a square canvas with whitespace around it.

Either way, this tutorial should point you in the right direction

http://return-true.com/2009/02/making-cropping-thumbnails-square-using-php-gd/

Comment: Thanks that tutorial was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GD library for what, with a library called [Wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) it's a breeze:

```
$image = WideImage::load('img_form_field_name');
$size = max($image->getHeight(), $image->getWidth());
$white = $image->allocateColor(255, 255, 255);
$image->resizeCanvas($size, $size, 'center', 'center', $white);
```

See the [documentation](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/) and [examples](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/), many functions can even be [tested interactively](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/?demo=resizeCanvas).

Answer (score 1):

Yep you'll want to look into either the [GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) or [ImageMagik](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). There are plenty of tutorials available for this task.

Functions like [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) etc will allow you to create a new image, and then stack the uploaded image on top of it and save it as a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: The question is more specific than simply "Is this possible", please read carefully. The way you chose to answer (just a link to docs with no other direction) just feels a bit rude and condescending.